# Proving that a L-algebraic Set is also a K-algebraic set

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, extension-field

The following question is from assignment 1 of my algebraic geometry course. I have been following only my class notes.

> Question: Let L|K be a field extension and $V\subseteq  L^n$ be an L-algebraic set. Then show that the set $V_K = V\cap K^n$ of all K-rational points of V is an K-algebraic set.

V is an L-algebraic set implies that V={ $a =(a_1,...,a_n) \in L^n |  f_i(a) =0 $ for all i from 1 to j } and each $f _i$ is a polynomial with coefficients in L.

The K-rational points of V is defined as, are $V_K =${$a =(a_1,...,a_n) \in K^n | f_i(a) =0 $ for all i from 1 to k } and each  $ f_i$ is a polynomial with coefficients in K.

I have been given $V_K= V\cap K^n$, all elements of $V \cap K^n$( say a) are elements of $K^n$ for which  $f_i(a) =0$  for all i from 1 to j  and each $f _i$ is a polynomial with coefficients in L.

To prove that V is a K-algebraic set in $K^n$, I have to show that all the coefficients in L of $f_i(a) =0$ are actually in K.

> But I am at loss of ideas on which theorem should I use?

Can you please shed some light on this on how should I prove it?

Comment: "To prove that V is a K-algebraic set in Kn, I have to show that all the coefficients in L of fi(a)=0 are actually in K." No, you don't have to. What you REALLY need to do it to prove that your intersection may be defined as the set of commons zeroes of polynomials with coefficients in $K$, which may be different from the $f_i's$. 

If $L/K$ is algebraic separable, this is easy: take the Galois closure $E/K$ of the field extension generated by the coefficients of all the $f_i's$, and set $g_i=\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(E/K)}\sigma\cdot f_i$. Then, $V\cap K^n$ is the set of zeroes of the $g_i's$.

Comment: I don't know how to proceed of $L/K$ is not separable, or if the extension is transcendental, and i'm not sure it is even true, but I'm not an expert on the subject. Maybe someone will come up with a solution which works for all extensions $L/K$ or a counterexample in the two missing cases.

Answer (score 1):

This the Exercise I.1.4 by E. Kuntz (1985) *Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry*. Birkhäuser.

For my personal comfort: I change the notations.

---

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field, let $\mathbb{F}$ be an extension field of $\mathbb{K}$ and let $V$ be and algebraic affine variety in $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{F}}$ (the $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}$-affine space).

If $V\cap\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}=\emptyset$ there is nothing to prove; otherwise...

By definition:
$$
\exists f_1,\dots,f_r\in\mathbb{F}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]:V=\{P\in\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{F}}\mid\forall l\in\{1,\dotsc,r\},f_l(P)=0\}\equiv\mathcal{Z}(f_1\dotsc,f_r);
$$
let $\mathcal{I}(V)=(f_1,\dotsc,f_r)$ be the ideal generated by these polynomials, considering
\begin{gather*}
\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]\xrightarrow{\overline{\epsilon}}\mathbb{F}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathbb{F}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]_{\displaystyle/\mathcal{I}(V)}\to0,\,\varphi=\pi\circ\overline{\epsilon},\\
\ker(\varphi)=\left\{p\in\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]\mid\pi\left(\overline{\epsilon}(p)\right)=0\right\}=\dotsc=\{p\in\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]\mid\forall X\in V,\,p(X)=0\},
\end{gather*}
and $\ker(\varphi)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$; by the *Hilbert's Basis Theorem*, this ideal is finitely generated, so there exist $g_1,\dotsc,g_s\in\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ such that $\ker(\varphi)=(g_1,\dotsc,g_s)$.

By previous step, one has:
$$
V\cap\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}\subseteq\mathcal{Z}(\ker(\varphi))\equiv V_0
$$
where $V_0$ is an affine algebraic variety in $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}$; without loss of generality, one could assume $V_0$ irreducible.

Since:
$$
V=\mathcal{Z}(f_1,\dotsc,f_r)=\bigcap_{l=1}^r\mathcal{Z}(f_l)\equiv\bigcap_{l=1}^rV_l,
$$
without loss of generality one could assume $r=1$. And by previous steps:
$$
\forall k\in\{1,\dotsc,s\},\,\overline{\epsilon}(g_s)\in\mathcal{I}(V)=(f_1)\equiv(f),
$$
this is equivalent to state:
$$
\exists q_1,\dotsc,q_s\in\mathbb{L}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]\mid\forall k\in\{1,\dotsc,s\},fq_k=g_k.
$$
By all this:
$$
V_0=\mathcal{Z}(g_1,\dotsc,g_s)=\dotsc=\left(V\cap\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}\right)\cup\left(\mathcal{Z}(q_1,\dotsc,q_s)\cap\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}\right),
$$
passing to closure operator:
$$
V_0=\overline{V}_0=\dotsc=\overline{\left(V\cap\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}\right)}\cup\overline{\left(\mathcal{Z}(q_1,\dotsc,q_s)\cap\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}\right)};
$$
by irreducibility of $V_0$ and by hypothesis:
$$
\overline{\left(\mathcal{Z}(q_1,\dotsc,q_s)\cap\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}\right)}=\emptyset\Rightarrow\left(\mathcal{Z}(q_1,\dotsc,q_s)\cap\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}\right)=\emptyset
$$
and therefore $V_0=\left(V\cap\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}\right)$.